Beep package distorted Kick drum audio
I am using the go lang beep package imported from [github.com/gopxl/beep](github.com/gopxl/beep) for one shot audio playback to a rhythm generator program. I have exported using Logic Pro various drum sounds (rimshot, sidestick, hh, kick, tambourine). All the sounds are played back perfectly from the Go program except for the kick that comes out distorted. Various artefacts appear at the beginning and end of the kick sound.
I have tested all the audio files which are 44,1Khz 24 bits and they all play perfectly outside the Go program. They are all properly gained staged and fade ins and outs are applied for the export. The kick sound is exported with linear EQ Low Cut and High Cut filters applied. I have also tried to set a constant buffer length for all audio files and call the streamer method inside the speaker call like I did for the other sounds:
speaker.Play(buf.kick.Streamer(0, buf.kick.Len())
These are the imports relevant to audio playback

    "github.com/gopxl/beep"
    "github.com/gopxl/beep/speaker"
    "github.com/gopxl/beep/wav"

This is how I make the buffer
type Buffer struct {
    snr           *beep.Buffer
    side          *beep.Buffer
    hh            *beep.Buffer
    clickDownBeat *beep.Buffer
    click         *beep.Buffer
    kick          *beep.Buffer
}

func Ui() {
    w := &Widgets{}
    p := &Parameters{}
    p.pattern = new(string)
    buf := &Buffer{
        kick:          makeBuffer("./wav/kick.wav"),
        snr:           makeBuffer("./wav/rim.wav"),
        side:          makeBuffer("./wav/side.wav"),
        hh:            makeBuffer("./wav/hh.wav"),
        clickDownBeat: makeBuffer("./wav/ride_bell.wav"),
        click:         makeBuffer("./wav/tambourine.wav"),
    }
    
        // rest of the UI func

func makeBuffer(file string) *beep.Buffer {
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    streamer, format, err := wav.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    speaker.Init(format.SampleRate, format.SampleRate.N(time.Second/35))

    buffer := beep.NewBuffer(format)
    buffer.Append(streamer)
    streamer.Close()
    return buffer
}

and this is how the buffer is streamed
func playSpeaker(char rune, w *Widgets, buf *Buffer) {
    switch {
    case char == 'O': // this is the problematic sound
        kick := buf.kick.Streamer(0, buf.kick.Len())
        speaker.Play(kick)
    case char == 'X':
        speaker.Play(buf.snr.Streamer(0, buf.snr.Len()))
    case char == 'x':
        if !w.muteFillsCheck.Checked {
            speaker.Play(buf.side.Streamer(0, buf.side.Len()))
        } else {
            return
        }
    case char == 'o':
        if !w.muteOffsetsCheck.Checked {
            speaker.Play(buf.hh.Streamer(0, buf.hh.Len()))
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
}

This is how playSpeaker is called from the play func:
// handling of clock,  change bpm and UI updates are handled prior to the for loop

for i, char := range *p.pattern {
    select {
        // click is a struct chan signal sent from a clock func in regular intervals 
    case <-click: 
        go playSpeaker(char, w, buf)
    case <-stopPlayChan:
        return
        }   
}

I 've only included here what I think is relevant to the problem however if anyone wants to check out the rest of the file or package you can see it here:
gitHub play.go
The wav files are also included in this folder:
GitHub wav Folder
